# How do I convert XML data to a table to search through like below?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, html, html-table

I'm need to figure out how to add the below XML data to the table below following the same structure so as to allow searching through the table as done through the table using below code. Shown through Jsfiddle link at bottom of page.

XML Data I'd like to be added to table:

```
  var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</AlbumName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</AlbumName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe></All>";
```

This is the format of the table which I normally search through (which I'd like to be created using XMLdata variable ShoesXML:

```
    <input type="text" id="search">
<table>
<thead>
   <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Brand Name</th>
        <th>Release Date</th>
        <th>Picture</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><span>All Stars</span></td>
        <td>Converse</td>
        <td>10/2/08</td>
        <td><img src="pic.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span>All Stars1</span></td>
        <td>Converse1</td>
        <td>11/2/08</td>
        <td><img src="pic1.jpg"/></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Code that I normally use to search through above table structure using textbox:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$("#search").on("keyup paste", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
    var $rows = $("table tr");

    $rows.each(function(index) {
        if (index !== 0) {
            $row = $(this);
            var column1 = $row.find("td:first span").html().toUpperCase();
            if (column1.indexOf(value) > -1) {
                $row.show();
            }
            else {
                $row.hide();
            }
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

Current procedure Jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/AYXG4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML is off, as BrandName is closed by the tag AlbumName. However, once that is fixed (as in the `ShoesXML` string below), something like this should work:

```
var ShoesXML = "<All><Shoe><Name>All Stars</Name><BrandName>Converse</BrandName><ReleaseDate>10/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe><Shoe><Name>All Star1s</Name><BrandName>Converse1</BrandName><ReleaseDate>11/2/08</ReleaseDate><Picture>pic.jpg</Picture></Shoe></All>";

$(document).ready(function() {  
  xmlDoc=$.parseXML( ShoesXML );
  $(xmlDoc).find("Shoe").each(function(i, n) {
        var html = "<tr>\n" + 
            "<td><span>" + $(n).find("Name").text() + "</span></td>\n" +
            "<td>" +  $(n).find("BrandName").text() + "</td>\n" +
            "<td>" + $(n).find("ReleaseDate").text() + "</td>\n" + 
            "<td><img src='" + $(n).find("Picture").text() + "'></td>\n" +
            "</tr>";
        $("table.shoetable tbody").append(html);
    });
});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JhFhd/2/

What the above code does is parse your XML using jQuery, then finds the appropriate columns within each `Shoe` tag and generates your HTML table row. From there, it appends it to the `tbody` section of the table with the class `shoetable`. Since it is appended to your table structure, your search function should work fine.

You can optimize the above some, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Quick question, if I identify the table by the class shoetable. How could I make the above code work specifically on that table?

Comment: I updated the fiddle link and the answer to respond only to the `tbody` section within `<table class="shoetable">`.